# Android: Transformations.switchMap not triggered when quick call

Tags: android, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack

I'm attempting to learn MVI. I am updating a state event live data that is being observed by a Transformations switch map. This is in my viewmodel.

```
fun setStateEvent(event: StateEvent) {
    Timber.d("SetStateEvent: [$event]")
    _stateEvent.value = event
}

val dataState: LiveData<DataState<CustomViewState>> = Transformations.switchMap(_stateEvent) { stateEvent ->
    Timber.d("Got state event [$stateEvent]")
    stateEvent?.let {
        handleStateEvent(it)
    }
}
```

Now in my view, I am trying to perform two actions:

```
viewmodel.setStateEvent(CustomStateEvent.ActionOne())
viewmodel.setStateEvent(CustomStateEvent.ActionTwo())
```

These are my logs:

```
SetStateEvent: [CustomStateEvent$ActionOne]
SetStateEvent: [CustomStateEvent$ActionTwo]

Got state event [CustomStateEvent$ActionTwo]
...
```

For some reason, the first one is getting cancelled/ignored. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LiveData` is a state holder and it's designed to serve this purpose. So it guarantees that all active (whose state is at least `STARTED`) observers will eventually receive the latest value of this `LiveData`, but all intermediate values can be conflated. If you need all the posted values to be delivered without conflation, you should use another abstraction - e.g [kotlin channel](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html#channel-basics).